# Output going beyond specified maximum in range() function

Tags: python, for-loop, range, conditional-statements

I am trying to answer the following practice question:

"Write a loop (we suggest a for loop) that prints the numbers from minimum to maximum, including minimum and maximum themselves. If even is True, print only the even numbers. If even is False, print only the odd numbers. You may assume minimum will always be less than maximum."

For this I have written the following code, and it works for certain minimum and maximum values:

```
minimum = 5
maximum = 14
even = True

if even:
    for numbers in range(minimum, maximum+1, 2):
        if numbers%2 == 0:
            print(numbers)
        elif numbers%2 == 1:
            numbers += 1
            print(numbers)
else:
    for numbers in range(minimum, maximum+1, 2):
        if numbers%2 == 1:
            print(numbers)
        elif numbers%2 == 0:
            numbers += 1
            print(numbers)
```

This generated my desired output of `6, 8, 10, 12, 14`.

However, once my minimum, maximum and even values are altered, to below for example:

```
minimum = 29
maximum = 33
even = True
```

The code somehow generates an output of `30, 32 and 34`. 34 > 33 and therefore it shouldn't be there, yet it is. I was under the assumption that `range()` works such that it doesn't include the maximum number and thus I used `maximum+1` to include `maximum` as the question asked, yet it included a number that is even beyond `maximum+1`!

To test further, I tried altering the variables as following and discovered something as interesting as it is puzzling too:

```
minimum = 1
maximum = 4
even = False
```

As expected, I got `1, 3` as my output. However, when I changed `minimum = 2`, I got `3, 5` as my output instead!

Could someone please explain to me why the code is acting this way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Side note: in your `else` block, you used `number` instead of `numbers`.

Comment: I have made the change, thanks!

Comment: Try to simulate the final numbers (in your head or using a debugger), you'll find that `numbers += 1` is causing your 34's or 5's. I'll leave the fix up to you. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
mn, mx, even = 5, 14, True

for x in range(mn + int(bool(mn % 2) == even), mx + 1, 2):
    print(x)
```

int() converts a bool value inside to either 0 or 1, which is the necessary offset for starting.

PS To understand why you ran out of range in your code, assume `numbers = 33`, plug it in your code, and see what happens:

```
    if numbers%2 == 0:
        print(numbers)
    elif numbers%2 == 1:
        numbers += 1
        print(numbers)
```

Comment: The `int()` actually isn't necessary, as `bool` is a subclass of `int` and `False` is `0` while `True` is `1`. You're already using this fact when you compare `mn % 2` to `even`. :)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 True : ) To continue, neither is the bool conversion necessary: `mn + (mn % 2 == even)`

Comment: Oh; I didn't even see the `bool()` call. >.> That's why I thought you were already comparing an `int` to a `bool` inside the `int()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you are in the for loop you are incrementing `number` variable, wich is the loop index, and should be managed by the loop itself.

Specifically when number is `33` when you reach

```
elif numbers%2 == 1:
    numbers += 1
    print(numbers)
```

it gets incremented by 1 and being 34 even it gets printed.

May I suggest an implementation:

```
for number in range(minimum, maximum+1):
    if (number%2 == 0 and even):
        print number
    elif (number%2 != 0 and not even):
        print number
```

Answer (score 0):

When `maximum` is 33 and you make a `range` object that goes to `maximum+1`, the largest value you're going to see from it is `maximum`, which is 33. However, when you add 1 to that value with `numbers += 1`, you change that to 34, which is where you get 34. You can clean up your code by changing `minimum` and `maximum` as necessary before you start, rather than shifting every number in the `range`.

```
def printer(low, hi, even):
    for num in range(low + (even == low%2), hi+1, 2):
        print(num)
```